# Inf sup condition for discrete Stokes problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, calculus-of-variations, navier-stokes

I am considering the discrete inf-sup condition for the discrete Stokes problem

$ \inf_{q \in Q_h} \sup_{v \in V_h} \frac{(q, \nabla \cdot v)}{\| q \| \| \nabla v\|} \geq \beta > 0$

This means that
$ \inf_{q \in \mathbb{R}^p} \sup_{v \in \mathbb{R}^n} \frac{v^T B q}{\| q \| \| v\|} \geq \beta > 0$

Can a do the following argumentation:

$ \inf_{q \in \mathbb{R}^p} \sup_{v \in \mathbb{R}^n} \frac{v^T B q}{\| q \| \| v\|}  = \inf_{q \in \mathbb{R}^p, \|q \| = 1 } \sup_{v \in \mathbb{R}^n, \| v \| = 1} v^T B q = \inf_{q \in \mathbb{R}^p, \|q \| = 1 } |B q|$

Is this correct? Or am I missing something?

I would be very grateful about any help.

Best,
frieder

Comment: I do not know what are $B_h$ and $Q_h$, but after that everything is ok.

Comment: ok, I should have mentioned more details. $Q_h$ is a finite element pressure space and $B$ is then the matrix related to $(q,\nabla \cdot v)$